# WindowFromPoint behind a window

Tags: winapi

I wrote a screenshot application/firefox addon which overlays each monitor with its own window. In the window the screenshot is drawn and is an editor.

I have a feature for user to "Select window at point" I am using [MSDN :: WindowFromPoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. This is however returning to me my editor window which is overlaying everything. Is it possible to get the window that is immeidately behind my window? Maybe some how to make it ignore my editor window?

If you would like to see what I mean please install my addon to firefox you can see how it works (it doesnt have the "Window at point" feature though) https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nativeshot/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use EnumWindows to scan the list of all the windows in the system, for each window call GetWindowRect to get the window location and check if the point is in the window.

Another option is to hide the overlay, call GetWindowFromPoint and reshow the overlay, however, if the overlay isn't fully transparent this will cause a visible blinking effect

Comment: Ah I think you're right this will be only way. Thanks @nir

Comment: Thanks for that hide and show idea, i tried it and it was a very bad blink :(

Comment: @Noitidart - I updated my answer with another option, however that other option only really works if your overlay is fully transparent